# text classification using keras input dimensions

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I used to do text classification on sklearn. However, I have to do it using keras, so I followed this tutrial to encode the labels and so on as I have little experience with NN: https://www.opencodez.com/python/text-classification-using-keras.htm.
However, I found out that I have to specify the input dimensions for the first layer.I am confused how can I decide a dimension of the text as an input? is it depending on the countvectroizer I did? as I preprocess the text as following:

```
corpus=[]
for i in range(0,len(dataset)):
    review=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ',dataset['cleaned_text'][i])
    review.lower()
    review=review.split()
    ps=PorterStemmer()
    review=[ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    review=' '.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)

#the bag of word
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv=CountVectorizer(max_features=1500).fit(corpus)
X=cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
y=dataset['sentiment']
```

Also, in the tutial he defined it based on the the vocab size. as far as I understand, I think the input dimensions should be the maximum number of tokens in the all sentence. right?
Also, I tried to get encoder.vocab_size as this tutrial did https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn. however, I got this error `AttributeError: 'LabelBinarizer' object has no attribute 'vocab_size'`

Comment: In the example, vocab_size = 15000, and later the input of the first layer is model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(vocab_size,))).

Comment: I know, but I want to what is 15000 really is? in order to be able to calculate it in my classifier

Comment: It is the maximum number of tokens you extract from your corpus and which the algorithm uses for the classification based on token counts..

Comment: so it's the lenghth of the maximum text in the inputs?

Comment: No, you break all your documents into a common pool of tokens and select 15000 tokens (in this example) out of the pool to pass to the classification algorithm. Say you have 10 documents, each has a different number of sentences and each sentence has a different length. You break every thing into tokens (most often just words) and use the token frequency as the data for classification.